# Designing an authorization architecture

Tags: node.js, postgresql, authorization, roles

I am currently designing a system where our clients can manage their data.

For the sake of simplicity, let's say I have two clients: "Netflix" and "HBO".
Each client has multiple users, all with the same role (but this might change in the future).

A client has one or more TV shows, a TV show has one or more seasons, a season has one or more episodes.

Attached is the database design I came up with, very simplified. I'm planning on using a relational database, likely Postgresql.

My main question is: where do I deal with authorization?

It shouldn't be allowed for users from HBO to CRUD any resources from Netflix, and vice versa.

My idea is to have a Login endpoint first where I return a JWT. That JWT will then be added to any future requests in the header, and will contain the user id.

Whenever I make a POST request to any of the resources, I can then read that resource ID from the URL and the user ID from the JWT, but how would I deal with the authorization in the most effective way?

For example, if I make a POST request to `api/episodes/1` to update the length of an episode then I have the three main pieces of information: `userId` from the JWT, `episodeId` from the URL and `time` from the body, but then my SQL would look something like this:

```
update episodes e
left join seasons s on e.season_id = s.id
left join shows sh on s.show_id = sh.id
left join clients c on sh.client_id = c.id
left join users u on c.id = u.client_id
set time = 60
where e.id = 1
and u.id = 1;
```

which seems pretty inefficient to me, if I have to write this for every query. And what if I later want to add some layers in between. maybe a season will laters consist out of 1 or more parts, and then each episode will belong to one part. then I have to update a lot of code.

Are there any better solutions for this? Something I can deal with this in code rather than on database level, and instead can just do simply:

```
update episodes
set time = 60
where id = 1;
```

And I already know that the user who tries to do this will have the correct rights?

The proposed stack for me to use is Node.js (typescript) + Express, in case that helps.

[image: Simplified view]

Comment: I suggest you read on how so called *multitenant* applications are designed and what options you have. The topic is too broad to provide a single answer as there are multiple valid solutions. One of the ways is to mark all the data in your database with the tenant name (hbo, netflix), issue the tenant name as one of JWT attributes upon authentication and then adding the tenant name to each query so that it acts as a global filter that prevents users from different tenants to see data from other tenants. However, this comment is only the tip of the iceberg.

Comment: let's start by breaking your issues down correct me if I'm wrong, but right now you need to figure out how to handle user authorization, correct?
for that, you can always use your current approach is good enough, a login returns JWT and saves the session id to cookie
a middleware you handle the authorization

next question, monolith or microservice architecture?

Comment: If it really is only two clients, you could use a database user per client and use row-level security to enforce your requirements.

Comment: @WiktorZychla thanks! I read up a bit on multitenant applications and that's exactly what I meant, didn't know the term before and this has been super helpful!

Comment: @Sammy for now; monolith

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe it's not only two clients, it was just meant as demo purposes

Comment: If you have specific questions on multitenant architecture, feel free to create new questions. As for now, I believe your question is too broad.